# DocuSign Rest API: Is it possible to manually set the time of day for an envelope to expire?

Tags: docusignapi, envelope

We are building an app that utilizes the DocuSign Rest API to create contracts/envelopes and send them on the fly.

We have found expireEnabled, expireAfter, and expireWarn in the documentation, but they only allow the user to set the expiration to a number of days after the envelope is sent.  I assume a cronjob of some sort mass expires envelopes at night.

However, a good number of our clients want to be able to set the exact time of expiration.  For example, to give a customer exactly 36 hours to accept an offer and sign the contract, and if it is not signed before then, our client can release a hold and make a similar offer to another customer.

The best we can think of is to store the expiration time ourselves and create our own cronjob that runs once a minute to manually void an envelope via the Rest API.  We're hoping a DocuSign rep (or some superuser) can step in and tell us if they already have something built for this or if we'll need to build it ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, currently there is no way to expire at a specific time. Voiding on a cronjob every minute with a valid void reason sounds like a great solution if your clients need it down to a timerange less than a day.

Comment: That's what I feared.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Including some details of a test I ran back in 2014 below on the various emails that go out and the times they dispatch. Correct in that there is no way to explicitly mark the time for when an envelope expires, simply just the day.

Email timestamps below are EST

- [Envelope Activation Email: Tue, Dec 23, 2014 at 12:59 PM]
- [Reminder Email: Wed, Dec 24, 2014 at 5:52 AM]
- [Expiration Pending Email: Thu, Dec 25, 2014 at 5:12 AM]
- [Reminder Email #2: Fri, Dec 26, 2014 at 4:58 AM]
- [Voided Email: Sat, Dec 27, 2014 at 4:53 AM]

Email reminder/expiration settings
Send a reminder email to the signer in: 1 day(s)
After the first reminder, send a reminder every: 1 day(s) 
Expire envelope in 3 day(s)
Warn signer of expiration: 1 day(s) before

So envelope created on 12/23. To determine expiration date, take 12/23 (creation) + 3 (expire envelope setting) + 1 extra day (padding as to not prematurely expire/void envelope) = 12/27 (early morning)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was seeing as well.  Thanks for the input.